# Mounting an external SSD with user privileges using fstab

Tags: bash, mount, fstab

I have entered the following command:

```
sudo mount UUID=17F30CD71ED138A1  -o gid=1000,uid=1000 ~/sandisk_external_drive
```

It worked great, but now I'd like to mount it on boot, therefore I have added an entry into the table: **/etc/fstab**. the following entry is:

```
UUID=17F30CD71ED138A1             /home/<my-user>/sandisk_external_drive nfs uid=1000,gid=1000,defaults 0 0
```

BUT I keep getting:

```
> mount.nfs: no mount point provided usage: mount.nfs remotetarget dir
> [-rvVwfnsh] [-o nfsoptions] options:
>         -r              Mount file system readonly
>         -v              Verbose
>         -V              Print version
>         -w              Mount file system read-write
>         -f              Fake mount, do not actually mount
>         -n              Do not update /etc/mtab
>         -s              Tolerate sloppy mount options rather than fail
>         -h              Print this help
>         nfsoptions      Refer to mount.nfs(8) or nfs(5)
```

What's wrong with this line?? I have tried multiple times and it fails.
I think the reason for the problem is the **options** fourth column which for some reason is not configured correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mounting it as **nfs** filesystem, knowing that it's a **local** drive.

Just replace `nfs`  with `ntfs`  : the correct `drive format` or `filesystem type` in your fstab.

Comment: But this is the correct filesystem type, I have checked it using lsblk. Output is:

```/dev/sdb                                                              
└─/dev/sdb1 ntfs     Sandisk_SSD 17F30CD71ED138A1                     /home/<my-user>/sandisk_external_driv```

Comment: The nfs is a network boot, NTFS is a Windows type formatting that does not support Linux ownership & permissions, so those are only set by mount command. For external devices, may also want to add the nofail option, so boot continues even when that device isn't available.
The nofail option is best combined with the x-systemd.device-timeout option. You may want noauto also. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab#Automount_with_systemd & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047109/how-can-i-delay-mount-of-secondary-internal-hard-drive-on-boot?noredirect=1#comment1710066_1047109

Comment: `ntfs` is not `nfs`

Comment: That's it :)....

Comment: Ohh wow, what a silly mistake, I accidently copy&pasted my NAS line and left it NFS.
Thank you all guys!!!

Answer (score 2):

For some reasons you specify `nfs` instead of `ntfs-3g`.

Here's how I mount my NTFS partitions in Linux:

```
UUID=0123456789ABCDEF /mnt/win ntfs-3g defaults,noatime,nofail,uid=1000,fmask=0133,dmask=0022,nls=utf8
```

```
noatime     - to disable updating last access time on reading files
nofail      - in case the device is not present on boot
nls=utf8    - to properly convert NTFS filenames to Linux
fmask/dmask - to prevent other users from modifying files/folders
```