Trying to mount a drive, but Mint can't find it?
I'm trying to mount the NTFS partition as described here https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-mount-partition-with-ntfs-file-system-and-read-write-access
The system is installed on sda5 and mounting sda1 is no problem.
But for sdb1 and sdb2 I get "No such file or directory", but they can be seen with fdisk:


Please don’t post images of text, for various reasons; see: PSA: Please don’t post images of text.  Instead, copy the text and paste it here as a code block.  (E.g., use “code fences” — see Markdown Editing Help and click on “show more”.)

Do you see any output from the kernel when you attempt this mount? See e.g. the output of journal -k or dmesg.

Was the disk in question last used on a Windows system with the "Fast boot" setting enabled?
The Windows "Fast Boot" (Windows defaults to "ON") setting leaves the disk partition in an undocumented, proprietary state that Linux isn't permitted to recognize. Boot back into Windows and disable "Fast Boot". Be prepared to have to re-disable "Fast Boot"  - Windows updates have been known to turn it back on. See https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup

"but they can be seen with fdisk" – fdisk does not see them, it assumes them. E.g. if you do fdisk -l foo and foo is a regular file which happens to have a valid partition table then the tool will show you foo1, foo2 etc., despite the fact such files are most likely not there in the directory. Similarly /dev/sdb1 may or may not be there. It should be there, but the right tool to verify this is ls -ld /dev/sdb*, not fdisk. If you accidentally removed /dev/sdb1 special file or if for any other reason it's not there then No such file is totally justified. So is the file there?

You did create the mount point, before you tried to mount it? sudo mkdir /mnt/big1 If internal drive better to mount with fstab, so always mounted when you reboot. If external drive you can mount with fstab, but need extra parameters to skip if not connected. https://askubuntu.com/questions/22215/why-have-both-mnt-and-media  & https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/622547/mounting-an-external-ssd-with-user-privileges-using-fstab Also discussion of ntfs3 vs ntfs-3g. https://www.heiko-sieger.info/does-the-linux-ntfs3-driver-corrupt-directories/ May depend on how new kernel is.

First, check to see if sdb1 and sdb2 are in /proc/partitions.  If they are, the problem lies in creation (or removal of) of the device nodes.
If they are not, try running partprobe /dev/sdb as root.  This will attempt to create the entries in /proc/partitions, and /dev/sdb1 and /dev/sdb2 based on the partitioning information.  Even if they are there, this might help.
If this works, a question becomes: Why didn't the boot process do this automatically?  There, I'm not sure.  Normally, these entries are created, assuming you are running udevd.
One other question:  Have you rebooted since this problem started?  (The boot process might fix it.)

I had some other problems with the Windows boot so I reinstalled everything again. I stopped hibernation and backup from Windows. Then tried your suggestions.
In /proc/partitions there was only 8       16 1953514584 sdb and after the command partprobe /dev/sdb there appeared 2 more lines: 8       17  204800000 sdb1
8       18 1748711424 sdb2
Then I tried again the mount command and got different response: ntfs-3g-mount: mount failed: Device or resource busy

That error typically means some other program is using the device.  It could be that the OS tried to mount it for you (try mount with not parameters, or cat /proc/mounts).  It could also be that ntfs-3g-mount could produce that error under other circumstances (like Windows's mounts not cleanly shutdown - windows likes to "suspend" rather than unmounting, as it makes for faster restarts).
